# Get html input controls and their values from html string

Tags: c#, html

I got `string str = "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"taken\" value=\"BoboBobo\">\n<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"took\" value=\"BaboboBe\""`

How do I get values from these input controls from html string using C#?

Comment: What are values you want to get?

Comment: The values of the input controls

Comment: ok, what are attributes of the `<input>` control you want to get?

Comment: use an html parser like Html Agility Pack: https://html-agility-pack.net

Answer (score 1):

You can use split and foreach:

```
string yourinputshidden = "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"taken\" value=\"BoboBobo\">\n<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"took\" value=\"BaboboBe\"";
string[] splitted = yourinputshidden.split(new[] { "\n<input" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
Dictionary<string, string> inputs = new Dictionary<string, string>(); // the list of inputs, by ID, Value
foreach(string item in splitted )
{
    string splittedAgain = item.split(new[] { "=\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string inputId = splittedAgain[3].replace("\"", "");
    string inputValue = splittedAgain[5].replace("\"", "");
    inputs.Add(inputId, inputValue);
}

// Continue your code
```

Comment: `.Split` is upper case, so this won't compile. `.Replace` is uppercase, so this won't compile. `.Split` returns an array, so the first line in the foreach won't compile. When you fix all that and run the code, you get an exception `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to achive your goal:

```
@"(?<=\svalue\s?=\s?\\"").*?(?=\\"")"
```

It is in an `@-quoted string`, so quotes must be `doubled`.

It starts by creating a `look behind` for: `'value=\"'`, then it matches `any characters` `not being a backslash` (zero or more times, non greedy), and finally `looks forward` for a `backslash` and a `double quote`.

**How to use:**

```
string text = "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"taken\" value=\"BoboBobo\">\n<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"took\" value=\"BaboboBe\"";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\svalue\s?=\s?\\"").*?(?=\\"")");
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(text))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

**Edit** according to comment, now it should Work.

Comment: All that has been fixed.

Comment: I think maybe you meant `new Regex("(?<=\\svalue\\s?=\\s?\\\").*?(?=\\\")")` ? Otherwise, this doesn't do anything. But that also fails on `text = "<input onclick='this.value=\"1\"' placeholder=' value = \"b\" 'value=\"a\" >";`

Comment: No, use an @-quoted string no double escaping is necessary.

Comment: If I copy the existing code, there's no console output. Maybe a different .net version?

Comment: What's worse, it can't fly to the moon. Please don't invent impossible cases.

Comment: Sure, bad solutions can work most of the time. The point is, html is not a regular language, and trying to parse it with (extended) regular expressions is going to fail, probably not in the way you were expecting. You can mitigate that risk and handle exceptions in a sane manner with a parsing library. Or you can take your chances and accept any bad data without warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to iterate over all <input>-values using a regular expression:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, "<input\\b.*?\\s+value\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"");
foreach (var match in matches)
  Console.WriteLine(((Match)match).Groups[1].Value);
```

This prints the values one by one to the console.

Maybe it's a good idea to create a generic dictionary for mapping the input ids to the values.

Comment: @BurnsBA You are right, I updated my code to regard whitespace characters around the equal sign.

Comment: Fixed that as well.

Comment: also fails on `var str = "<input onclick='this.value=\"1\"' placeholder=' value = \"b\" 'value=\"a\" >";`